# Does Quicksilver's walkman speed up with him?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In *Days Of Future Past*, Quicksilver spends a lot of time playing with electronics.  In his famous tour de force scene in the Pentagon, he specifically puts his headphones on before running around the kitchen.

But why?  Does the music on his Walkman speed up with him as he uses it, or is it still operating at "normal" speed? Or indeed, does any electronic device that he touches speed up?

Comment: The ping-pong table handled him, and more importantly, so did the video game "Pong." And when he touched the face of that guard (in *THAT* scene) you could see ripples immediately. I'm guessing it's with whatever he's having direct contact. He touches something and *it* slows down, but only while he's touching it. Kind of like [Kitty Pryde's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitty_Pryde) Phase power... Direct contact.

Comment: Maybe he had a slowed down version of music, so that it played at near about correct speed when he accelerated... :P

Comment: @MeatTrademark I assumed we could immediately see ripples on the guard's face because of the physical transfer of force. If Quicksilver's power affects everything he has "direct" contact with, then I don't think we'd see the air creating "waves" on his skin as he moves at high speed; i.e. why isn't the air speeding up with him?

Answer (score 21):

#### SPECULATION BASED ON OBSERVATIONS

Pietro Maximoff, in the canon Marvel Earth-616 continuity, was unable to "share" his speed with other beings or objects of a mechanical or computerized nature. One of his pet peeves in the Earth-616 continuity is the slowness of everything used by humans.

**In Days of Future Past:**

- The scene in the movie where he plays ping-pong by himself is an excellent way to introduce his power in the physical world.
- IF the movie has granted him a speed-sharing ability, this ability would explain why mechanical devices like his Walkman are able to play at a speed he could listen to in his accelerated rate.
- However, while this would work for the Walkman it does not explain the accelerated computerized Pong game.

#### However, if he is the same as the canon Quicksilver:

- This means the Walkman had to be modified to play music at a faster rate of speed for him to be able to hear it while he utilized his powers. He may have also used the music as a timing mechanism to consider how long he had before he would need to be done.

> **UPDATE:** A propmaster indicated Quicksilver's Walkman was a stolen prototype for a device originally patented as a stereo-belt created by Andreas Pavel--in 1972, a potentially real device that was never put into production. **REF: Tested.com: [X-men: A Tale of the Portable Tape](http://www.tested.com/art/movies/461631-x-men-tale-portable-tape/)**

[image]

The original idea actually has a patent image and specifications. A prototype was created and that device is what Quicksilver is supposedly using in the movie. It would be capable of being sped up sufficiently for his needs (though I suspect tapes would enjoy a much shorter lifespan due to the speed increase.)

[image]

[image]

- The video game would have also had to be sped up for his enjoyment, but it would require someone with specialize skills to do this by altering the game's rate of delivery. This would be possible if someone with the proper skills reprograms the game. It is conceivable he could have learned to do it himself.

#### A PLOT INCONSISTENCY

- Since he was able to perform two dozen feats in the few seconds once he attacked the guards, and the music played (for the audience) at the normal rate, it is implied he heard the music at the same rate but accelerated for his enjoyment.

**But that does not have to be the case. We are not sure what he is playing on his Walkman. I have also considered it may be nothing more than a means of focusing his attention to utilize his powers fully. It may not even be music at all.**

Answer (score 3):

A [Yahoo! Movies article about Quicksilver’s addition to the film](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/how-quicksilvers-standout-scene-in-x-men-days-of-87308240107.html) has a quote from editor John Ottman, who explains that it’s not a regular Walkman, but a souped-up prototype that he stole:

> How, in 1973, did Quicksilver possess that Croce-playing Walkman in the first place, given that technology didn’t emerge until the ’80s (and how does the music keep speed with him)? “Technically it’s not a Walkman,” Ottman explained. “There’s a whole backstory that’s never shown in the movie nor did we shoot it but **he supposedly had stolen this thing that was a prototype of Walkman technology from some lab somewhere… So it was supposed to be some original prototype that he happens to have.**”
>
> Ottman laughs. “But how would anyone know that?”

(Migrated from [a question that was closed as a dupe of this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/how-was-quicksilver-able-to-listen-walkman-during-pentagon-super-speed-fight-in/68171#68171); CW to avoid double-rep counting)

Answer (score 2):

I have never read a comic that implied quicksilver had the ability to affect the speed of other objects other than himself. Nothing I have looked up implies this either. Essentially he can run impossibly fast and is adapted to being able to do so. His body is able to withstand the pressures of running at those speeds without disintegrating or tiring. He also has strong legs.

Keep in mind any iteration or reboot of a character can add, manipulate, or otherwise change the powers and abilities of a character. It could be that this is some added upper limit of some kind or a simple movie mistake. I'm also not sure how he was able to run up and sideways on the wall. Did he just generate enough momentum?

Another important note that if Quicksilver in the movie could manipulate the speed of other objects than he would not have had to hold the back of Magneto's head to prevent whiplash. With regards to the ping pong table I don't think the ball is travelling at normal speeds and it looks he was just pressing the buttons really fast for the arcade game.

Comment: It would be impossible for him to play ping pong with himself unless he hit the ball at "normal" speeds. A regular human cannot play ping pong with themselves without hitting the ball slowly. If he hit the ball with the speed that he is capable of, he either would flatten the ball or not be able to reach his own shot. Assuming everything speeds up in a relative fashion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that he is using the music to keep time and pace. It didn't make sense until I realized his entire body is moving at that speed.

If everyone is standing still then they are processing information at normal speed, while his super speed allows him to process information at super speed. The music would sound like jumbled screech to everyone else, but since his brain can now process much more information in shorter time he is able to listen to the music in a way that would seem normal.

So he is not affecting the music, he just has a sped up song that he can use during his super speed.