# How was Quicksilver able to listen Walkman during Pentagon super speed fight in kitchen?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In *X-Men: Days of the Future Past* movie, there's a scene in Pentagon kitchen in which guards shoot bullet and Quicksilver puts his headphones ON to listen "Time in a Bottle" before playing as speed god.

Definitely, Sony Walkman of 70s can't play songs at 5000x. Can Quicksilver make other things faster? Or, it's a plot hole?

Comment: to me he seems to make almost like a time bubble around himself. everything hes doing he feels like its at normal speed and its everyone else that slowed down. anything touching him goes the speed hes going or is inside of his time bubble. OR its a plot hole :D(i mean he could have tampered with the walkman anyway and sped it up for himself) but i like my relativity time bubble idea better.

Comment: @Himarm Dont forget, he did touch bullets..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Yahoo! Movies article about Quicksilver’s addition to the film](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/how-quicksilvers-standout-scene-in-x-men-days-of-87308240107.html) has a quote from editor John Ottman, who explains that it’s not a regular Walkman, but a souped-up prototype that he stole:

> How, in 1973, did Quicksilver possess that Croce-playing Walkman in the first place, given that technology didn’t emerge until the ’80s (and how does the music keep speed with him)? “Technically it’s not a Walkman,” Ottman explained. “There’s a whole backstory that’s never shown in the movie nor did we shoot it but **he supposedly had stolen this thing that was a prototype of Walkman technology from some lab somewhere… So it was supposed to be some original prototype that he happens to have.**”
>
> Ottman laughs. “But how would anyone know that?”

Comment: Where do you get "souped-up" from, and from there, where do you get "specifically can play songs at 5000x"?

Comment: @Rawling “souped-up” is just meant to mean that this is an enhanced Walkman, not a regular model. I make no claims about 5000x speed specifically; that came from the OP.

Comment: OK, where do you get "enhanced" from?

Comment: @Rawling It’s a prototype that has capabilities beyond the standard model. Hence “enhanced”.

Comment: OK, where do you get "capabilities beyond the standard model" from?

Comment: @Rawling It plays music faster than a regular Walkman can. But this is getting silly – I’m leaving this conversation.